# High performance low latency C++ custom string class

Tags: c++, string

My goal is to find the fastest C++ library for casting int to string, vice versa, and parsing.

Anyone that has experimented with performance of C++ will quickly realize that the string class of [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) has terrible performance compared to say  STL int arithmetic operations.

Some sample benchmarks from my 3.3 GHz Intel, GCC, [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 5.5 machine:

```
memcpy        0.004000 microsec/op
atoi          0.025000 microsec/op
atof          0.133000 microsec/op
strtod        0.133000 microsec/op
atof          0.135108 microsec/op
(char) uchar  0.001801 microsec/op
(char) ushort 0.001801 microsec/op
cache accs    0.010505 microsec/op
maplookup     0.128534 microsec/op
add_int       0.002456 microsec/op
```

You can quickly see that string operations will become a bottleneck for any high speed messaging applications.

I have located other libs for high performance strings (listed), but I am writing hoping someone has had similar difficulty and has reached some solution, possibly including writing their own string class.

- http://bstring.sourceforge.net/
- http://code.google.com/p/stringencoders/
- http://www.and.org/vstr/comparison
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo.html

Comment: Well, you've done the benchmarks. But my question is: Does it really matter to optimize this class? Was a significant amount (> 20% of time) of time spent in actual string <-> numerical conversions? And also, why bother sending the numerical data as strings? It would be more efficient to simply send them in their native (or an intermediate, but still numerical) representation

Comment: do you have an application which you have profiled and identified a bottle-neck processing strings, or are you just surmising that it might be a bottle-neck in some hypothetical application?

Comment: I think you will find this is not really a bottleneck. Network latency will obscure any of these timings by several orders of magnitude.

Comment: So you need to convert values more that 10.000.000 times per second? Why?

Comment: mike bantegui, it would be faster to send in binary but that is not an option for this particular application as the receiving app must receive char arrays. chris card, yes it is a bottleneck. martin, yes network latency will obscure these timings but network latency doesn't determine how fast you can generate a response, which is what im optimizing. bo persson, yes i am targeting message processing rates @ several million per second

Comment: @pee kay: Then simply send the data as a char array. In C++, you can just cast it to a pointer to char and then send the data. The receiving end will receive the char array, and you can just cast it back to a numerical type.

Comment: @Mike Bantegui: that presumes the sender and receiver match the architectural attributes:  FPU format, endianness, possibly data type alignment.  @pee kay:  Converting everything to ASCII representation is a very good portability strategy.  If it doesn't exist that way for a good reason, it could be a good area to optimize, though my experience is that it is rarely worth it.

Comment: What about _Boost.Spirit_ ?

Comment: Why do you not have `std::to_string` and `std::stringstream` versions in the benchmark to support the claim of terrible performance? Also the functions seem to do different things, so they are not a fair comparison.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't provide much information about your servers, but have a look at these libraries from AMD and Intel:

[AMD String Library](http://developer.amd.com/cpu/Libraries/AMDStringLibrary/Pages/default.aspx)

[Intel Integrated Performance Primitives](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-ipp/)

Both use [SSE extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) to speed up string operations.

As far as I can see, they have no *atoi()*, but you could use the libraries to locate the decimals in the input. Given the string location and length it should be trivial to write a conversion using SSE intrinsics.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own string class ([gstring](http://code.google.com/p/libglim/source/browse/trunk/gstring.hpp)). It's header-only and allows me to reuse stack buffers and wrap C strings easily. Integer encoding is included. Integer decoding is a wrapper around strtol.

Allows me to parse strings easily:

```
uint32_t pos = 0
gstring gs1 = gstr.netstringAt (pos, &pos); // gs1 is a *view* into gstr
gstring gs2 = gstr.netstringAt (pos, &pos);
int int1 = gstr.intAt (pos, &pos); if (gstr[pos] == ',') ++pos;
int int2 = gstr.intAt (pos, &pos); if (gstr[pos] == ',') ++pos;
```

There's also [Str](https://freecode.com/projects/str-class), but its behaviour on a 64-bit platform isn't very clear to me.
There's also [FBString](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBString.md). They [promise](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/folly-the-facebook-open-source-library/10150864656793920) that "folly::to" conversions are fast.

Answer (score 0):

Send everything in ASCII hex, and write the conversion routines in assembly language.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at http://alexott.blogspot.fr/2010/01/boostspirit2-vs-atoi.html

It might give you a bigger performance boost if you are parsing something more complicated than a string.

But as some comments said, is there really a bottleneck with string manipulations? Can't you avoid them before hand?

Answer (score 0):

The authors of Boost Karma library did a comparison of several integer to string conversion methods [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/performance_measurements/numeric_performance/int_performance.html). In [this post](http://zverovich.net/2012/12/21/does-string-formatting-boost-karma.html) I did a similar comparison, but including the [format library](https://github.com/vitaut/format). You don't need a custom string class for this, for example, in case of the format library, the output is stored in an internal buffer which you can convert to an `std::string` or access as a C string or as an array of characters so you can avoid string creation if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

```
int castString( const char * str )
{
    int val = 0;
    while( *str ) {
        val = val*10 + (*str++ - '0');
    }
    return val;
}
```

This is very fast

Comment: And totally free of any error checking!  What a trusting soul you are.  Also this doesn't handle signed input so it should probably return unsigned int.